# Radeon HD 5770 - DisplayPort Problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, adapter, displayport, eyefinity

I am trying to set up 3 monitors with the Radeon HD 5770 I recieved a few days ago. I have read that I can use 2 DVI ports and an active DisplayPort adapter for a third DVI monitor.
I have purchased this adapter: http://www.accellcables.com/products/DisplayPort/DP/dp_dvid.htm

I have the two normal DVI monitors working, but when I try to extend the display to the third, I get a message saying the system has detected a problem with the connection through the display port which may limit resolution/refresh rate. I know that all the cables are fine, I have replaced the adapter, the monitors all work, I have tried different monitors through the adapter, and even nothing but the adapter, but I cannot get any monitor to work using it. I am trying to use 2 Dell monitors and an Acer. Have I overlooked something? Is there a compatibiliy issue I missed? Any suggestions as to what I could try? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When using a DisplayPort™ to dual link DVI dongle to connect the display to the computer, the monitor experiences one or more of the following symptoms:

Flickering
Flashing
Blinking
Possible causes:
The issue can be caused by, but is not limited to, one of the following conditions:

The DisplayPort™ dongle’s USB power connector is connected to a USB connector that does not supply sufficient power (USB low power load)
A USB hub that does not have an external power connection is being used
A USB connection on a motherboard or a USB hub is used that does not support the high power load option for USB
The DisplayPort™ dongle being used may have some design issues or may have a manufacturing quality issue
Damaged/Defective DisplayPort™ dongle
How to troubleshoot the issue:
The following troubleshooting tips can help identify and resolve the cause of the issue:

The DisplayPort™ dongle’s USB power connector is connected to a USB connector that does not supply sufficient power (USB low power load) 
The DisplayPort™ dongle must receive the required power to ensure it functions reliably. The USB connector used must be designed to supply a USB high power load (5V @ 500mA). A USB low power load (5V @ 100mA) can not be used 
Note! If the system experiences a loss of picture or flickering on a panel that is connected to a powered DisplayPort™ dongle, check the system BIOS for a USB low power or Stand-By option and disable it 
This can help prevent the motherboard from dropping the power of the USB bus below the required amount to operate the Active (powered) DisplayPort™ dongle, which may be the cause of the flickering and / or blank panel
A USB hub that does not have an external power connection is being used 
Ensure that the USB hub in use has its own separate power source
A USB connection on a motherboard or a USB hub is used that does not support the high power option for USB 
Ensure that the motherboard or powered hub USB connection in use supports USB high power. Refer to the manufacturer’s manual or website to determine if the USB connection in use meets this requirement (5V @ 500mA) 
If possible, try connecting the DisplayPort™ dongle to another available motherboard or powered USB hub USB connection to rule out any issues with the USB connection in use 
Note! If the system experiences a loss of picture or flickering on a panel that is connected to a powered DisplayPort™ dongle, check the system BIOS for a USB low power or Stand-By option and disable it 
This can help prevent the motherboard from dropping the power of the USB bus below the required amount to operate the Active (powered) DisplayPort™ dongle, which may be the cause of the flickering and / or blank panel
The DisplayPort™ dongle being used may have some design issues or may have a manufacturing quality issue 
The output from a DisplayPort™ dongle depends on the quality of the dongle used 
Refer to ATI Eyefinity Validated Dongles for a listing of recommended DisplayPort™ Dongles
Damaged/Defective DisplayPort™ Dongle 
Check both ends of the DisplayPort™ dongle to ensure there are no damaged pins 
Verify that the DisplayPort™ dongle cable is not damaged, creased or showing any exposed wires 
If possible, replace the DisplayPort™ dongle with another available dongle to rule out any issues with the DisplayPort™ dongle in use
Check with the motherboard or system manufacturer for any available updates for the motherboard’s VBIOS